# FPGA simulation doesn't match actual performance

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to write a verilog code that will trigger on the positive edge and negative edge of an input signal (which I've called 'async').  My desired output is a short blip (when compared to the frequency of async) on each edge of async, which is slightly delayed from the edge ('t1' and 't3') and whose duration can be controlled ('t2' and 't4').  The comments say what I think my code is doing, but I am new to Verilog, and don't really understand anything.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my full code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module attempt5(async, clk, o);

input async; 
input clk;
reg switch = 1'b0; //will tell me when async changes
reg [1:3] resync = 3'b000;
reg counter = 1'b0; //keeping track of which edge of async we're on
output reg o = 1'b0; 

parameter t1 = 0;
parameter t2 = 100000000;
parameter t3 = 0;
parameter t4 = 100000000;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
switch <= resync[2] & !resync[3];
switch <= resync[3] & !resync[2];
resync <= {async, resync[1:2]};
end
//^^I'm pretty sure this makes the 'switch' register switch very quickly when 'async' changes  
//I've included this always block because I wanted to sync my input signal to the clock, because I read that FPGAs don't do well with asynchronous stuff 


always @ (posedge switch)
if (counter == 1) begin
counter = 0;
#t1 o <= ~o;
#t2 o <= ~o;
end else begin
counter = 1;
#t3 o <= ~o;
#t4 o <= ~o;
end
//^^ When the 'switch' register changes, start the the short blip
endmodule
```

And my constraints file:

```
NET "clk" TNM_NET = "clk";
TIMESPEC TS_clk = PERIOD "clk" 20 ns HIGH 50 %;
NET "switch" TNM_NET = "switch";
TIMESPEC TS_switch = PERIOD "switch" TS_clk  HIGH 50 %;

NET "async" LOC = A2;
NET "o" LOC = C1;
INST "clk_BUFGP" LOC = F1;
NET "clk" LOC = F1;

NET "o" SLEW = FAST;
```

The code works in the synthesizer, but when I try to test the code using a 1 Hz square wave for the "async" signal and monitoring the "o" using a oscilloscope, nothing happens.

Other details: 
using a Xilinx XEM 6001 FPGA, and ISE Design Suite 14.4
The way I've tested is to hook up a function generator to pin A2 and a oscilloscope to pin C1, and all I see is noise. Is there any obvious problem here, maybe something like I am not actually connecting to the physical pins properly or something?

Comment: `#` delays are not synthesizable; there should be getting a warning in the log file.

Comment: @Greg If '#' delays are not synthesizable, is there another way to implement a delay?

Comment: You can use a counter that resets when a change is detected with your `async`

Answer (score 1):

Your second assignment to `switch` overrides the first one. That's the nature of a always block ...

Your intension is to create a edge detector for both edges, so you need to 'or' a rising and falling edge equation.

```
switch <= (resync[2] & !resync[3]) | (resync[3] & !resync[2]);
```

Or you use the apropiate boolean operator `xor` (aka not equal).

```
switch <= resync[2] ^ resync[3];
```